# Karma: Check not flushed requests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I write tests for angular app using karma, is any way i can check not flushed requests before $httpBacked.flush()? i need this because i dont know is request sent or not and if no, $httpBacked.flush() cause exception.

i need something like this:

```
it('should', function() {
    if($httpBackend.isRequestsPresent()) { 
        $httpBackend.flush(); 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()
```

to check on the requests send/not or expectations met/not met sent.

See also [here.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)

Comment: i dont think it actually what i need... this statements i can put in beforeEach() afterEach() blocks and it work like parcers.. i need something like this: if($httpBackend.isRequestsPresent()) { $httpBackend.flush(); }

Comment: I do not think this is possible, as the expectations are private and there is no interface to request them. Can you show an example of a test - it would be interesting to me how you set up your expectations. If you are setting expectations based on parameters in your tests, you should probably refactor them.

Comment: hmmm... i need reorganize my tests logic, and you was right, i cant do this (i read all documentation and cant find the way)